# How to test postgres trigger functions for various test cases in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, function, postgresql, triggers

I have the rails application and i use postgresql for database. I use trigger functions to make some changes in the database while there is changes happens in the application data. But i dont have a good idea on how to test the trigger functions with test cases...

Answer (score 1):

I'm in a similar boat on my end. I ended up writing unit tests that involved direct database insert/update/delete statements, and direct select statements to validate the changes.

As a tip, consider writing a few tests that manipulate multiple rows as once, and which verify that the number of affected rows returned is valid. In my experience the latter have a knack for revealing shortcomings (crashes, race conditions, etc.) when things are complex.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply do the same operation you do in the production application?

E.g. if your trigger incements a column value on an insert and update, just write a test for these events and test if the value was incremented correctly by retrieving it and checking it. So if a column value is "3" before the insert operation and "4" afterwards, you know that the trigger was fired correctly.